# Язык C, sizeof() и массивы

Tags: c, sizeof

Объясните пожалуйста, что не нравится компилятору? Я ведь передаю в **sizeof()** имя статичного массива, который содержит указатели на структуру **pack**. Хотел посмотреть реальный размер, а в итоге какая-то непонятная ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В заголовке нет размера массива, так-что нужно умножать самому:
`RING_QUEUE_SIZE * sizeof ( pack * )`

Comment: Или, как вариант, указать размер в extern'е: `extern pack *ring_queue[RING_QUEUE_SIZE];`.